# Query 2 sets of Sheets data & identify discrepancies

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to use Apps Script to query 2 datasets and compare certain columns across them.  I am hoping to...

**a)** identify missing ID values;

**b)** reconcile differences in other fields, when the ID values match.

INPUT:
Spreadsheet with 2 tabs (tab1, tab2).
The key ID in each B column (Btab1, Btab2)

- I want to identify instances where a unique value (B) is in one dataset but not in the other (the rows are not in the same order)
- Run a function & push to an output tab if Btab1 is not in tab2 || Btab2 is not in tab1
- When a value of B is in both tabs (the majority of the time), I want to identify instances of data discrepancies in a few columns...
- For all instances of B, push B and the relevant columns below to the output tab if...

  - Column M in tab1 doesn't match column E in tab2
  - Column P in tab1 <> column F in tab2
  - Column AN tab1 <> Column G tab2

OUTPUT: 
tab that displays problem areas in the datasets.
First column is ID Key.
Second column explains the issue via text string

*Again, the challenge here is that the values are not sorted the same, and there could be a slight difference in total # rows*

```
function compare() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   ss.insertSheet(1);
   ss.getActiveSheet().setName('output');
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('sheet2');
  var sheet_output = ss.getSheetByName('output');


  var range1 = sheet1.getRange(1,1,sheet1.getLastRow(),sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 
  var output1 = [];
  var a1;
  var b1;
  var h1;
  var i1;
  var j1;
  var m1;
  var o1;
  var p1;
  var an1;
  var ao1;
  var x;

  var range2 = sheet2.getRange(1,1,sheet2.getLastRow(),sheet2.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 
  var output2 = [];
  var a2;
  var b2;
  var c2;
  var d2;
  var e2;
  var f2;
  var g2;
  var h2;
  var y;

  /// can i do for(x in range1; y in range2) { all in one function??  If so, what is the proper syntax?

  for(x in range1, y in range2) {
    a1 = range1[x][0];
    b1 = range1[x][1];
    h1 = range1[x][7];
    i1 = range1[x][8];
    j1 = range1[x][9];
    m1 = range1[x][12];
    o1 = range1[x][14];
    p1 = range1[x][15];
    an1 = range1[x][39];
    ao1 = range1[x][40];

    a2 = range2[y][0];
    b2 = range2[y][1];
    c2 = range2[y][2];
    d2 = range2[y][3];
    e2 = range2[y][4];
    f2 = range2[y][5];
    g2 = range2[y][6];
    h2 = range2[y][7];

    if (

      (b1 != b2) ||
      (m1 != e2) // etc etc etc
       )
    {

  //push to output
  }}
```

Comment: Please share code by posting it in the question.

Comment: Also please post images of the sheets you are comparing.

Comment: @Cooper just shared code!  I can dummy up some data, but it is basically all stored as strings in Sheets, so by defining the variables we should be good :)

Comment: Do you want to update values in sheet1 and sheet2 in case of discrepancies or only push the values into the new sheet?

Comment: @ziganotschka I do not want to update values.  I want to identify discrepancies and create an output sheet for review.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Whilst your syntax `for(x in range1, y in range2)` will not return an error, it won't give you the desired result neither if the rows are not in the same order

Reason:

During each iteration both `x` and `y` will change, e.g. if `var range1 = [1,2,3]` and `var range2 = [4,5,6]`, your loop will iterate 3 times and the values in your sample loop iterations will be:

1. iteration

`range1[x] = 1` and `range2[y] = 4`

2. iteration

`range1[x] = 2` and `range2[y] = 5`

3. iteration

`range1[x] = 3` and `range2[y] = 6`

In this case you will not retrieve the combination

`range1[x] = 1` and `range2[y] = 4`

or

`range1[x] = 2` and `range2[y] = 6`

and so on.

Instead you need to use two nested for loops, which would iterate through all possible combinations of `x` and `y`:

```
 for(x in range1) {
    for(y in range2){
      ...
    } 
  }
```

**Sidenote:**

Even if your rows would be in the same order, you still need to be careful. Because `for(x in range1)` opposed to `for(x = 0; x < range1.length; i++)` gives you no control about in which folder the loop will iterate over the range.

**Now to your query for duplicates**

A possible way to implement the functionality in a not too complicated manner would be the following:

- Define boolean variable and use it to check for each `x` either it has a duplicate
- If a duplicate (for column B) is found - further criteria will be evaluated
- If two rows match by all criteria, the inner loop will be exited with `break` and the function will jump to the next `x`
- If rows with identical key IDs, but discrepancies in other columns are found - both rows will be pushed into sheet `output` for comparison purposes (this is easier to implement than specifying what exactly is discrepant)
- After this the inner loop will also be exited
- In oth cases above `duplicate` will be set to `true`
- If a unique Id is found in sheet1 (duplicate = false) - it will be immediately pushed into `output`

**Sample**

```
function compare() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   ss.insertSheet(1);
    ss.getActiveSheet().setName('output');
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('sheet2');
  var sheet_output = ss.getSheetByName('output');


  var range1 = sheet1.getRange(1,1,sheet1.getLastRow(),sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 
  var output1 = [];
  var b1;
  var m1;
  var p1;
  var an1;
  var x;

  var range2 = sheet2.getRange(1,1,sheet2.getLastRow(),sheet2.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 
  var output2 = [];
  var b2;
  var e2;
  var f2;
  var g2;
  var y;

  var array = [];
  for(x in range1) {
    var duplicate = false;
    for(y in range2){
      b1 = range1[x][1];
      m1 = range1[x][12];
      p1 = range1[x][15];
      an1 = range1[x][39];    

      b2 = range2[y][1];
      e2 = range2[y][4];
      f2 = range2[y][5];
      g2 = range2[y][6];

      if (        
        (b1 == b2)
      )
      {
        Logger.log("found");
        duplicate = true;
        if((m1 != e2)||
        (p1 != f2) ||
        (an1 != g2)){
          array.push(range1[x]);
          array.push(range2[y]);
        }
        break;          
      }
    } 
    if (duplicate == false){
      Logger.log("duplicate false");
      array.push(range1[x]);
    }
  }
  //push to output
  if(array[0]){
    sheet_output.getRange(sheet_output.getLastRow()+1, 1, array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks this seems to be working with a few tweaks, appreciate the well written explanation of the code as well!